# Does it make sense to return an existential type?

Tags: scala, existential-type

If I define a method which returns an existential type:

```
trait X[T] {
  def hello(x: T):Unit = println(x)
}

def myX: X[_] = new X[Any] {}
```

If I invoke `myX`, I will get a value which has type `X[_]`, but I can't passing anything to it:

```
val y: Any = 123
myX.hello(y)  // compilation error!
```

Only I can do is passing a `Nothing`:

```
val y: Nothing = ???
myX.hello(y)  // compilable, but useless
```

So it doesn't make sense for a method to return an existential type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scala> trait X[T] {
     |   def hello(x: T):Unit = println(x)
     | }
defined trait X
```

Your definition of a function:

```
scala> def myX: X[_] = new X[Any] {}
myX: X[_]

scala> val xnothing = myX
xnothing: X[_] = $anon$1@5c44c582

scala> xnothing.hello(1)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: _$1
       xnothing.hello(1)
                      ^
```

"Fixed" definition of the same function - captures type arg properly:

```
scala> def myY[T]: X[T] = new X[T] {}
myY: [T]=> X[T]
```

If generic arg is not passed, infers `Nothing`.

```
scala> val ynothing = myY
ynothing: X[Nothing] = $anon$1@53f0a4cb
```

You can pass a generic arg explicitly.

```
scala> val yint = myY[Int]
yint: X[Int] = $anon$1@555cf22
```

Obviously `Int` is not `Nothing`.

```
scala> ynothing.hello(1)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: Nothing
       ynothing.hello(1)
                      ^
```

This obviously works because we passed `Int` explicitly:

```
scala> yint.hello(1)
1
```

Now this is an interesting part. It works because Scala can figure out that generic arg is `Int` (from usage). contrast it with `ynothing` definition above and its call `ynothing.hello(1)` which does not compile.

```
scala> myY.hello(1)
1
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make much sense to return *this* existential type, but they can be useful in other cases. As a trivial example

```
// method which returns an existential type
// note that you can't return Array[Any] here,
// because arrays aren't covariant in Scala (which is a good thing)
def array: Array[_] = if (some condition) Array[Int](...) else Array[Double](...) 

// all of following works
array(0)
array.length
// etc.
```

Of course, if you can write the precise generic type of a method, you should definitely prefer it.